# Can a punctured ball $(B\setminus\{0\})\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be foliated by complete leaves?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds, foliations

Recently Antonio Alarcón proved that in the case of the unit ball $B\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n\geq 2$ every smooth closed complex submanifold of dimension $q\leq n$, $V\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ defines a non-critical foliation on $B$ that includes $V$ by submanifolds of dimension $q$ that are complete (with the induced euclidean metric) except for perhaps $V$. This result implies that foliations by complete leafs are abundant in $B$ and results by Forstneric, Globevnik Drnovsek and others show that complete foliations are possible for certain pseudoconvex domains and Stein Manifolds.
Given that the punctured ball is not pseudoconvex it may be the case that there aren't any foliations by complete leaves in the punctured ball, but since they are so common in the ball, there must be an example of a folliation in the punctured ball by complete leaves.

Comment: By "there must be", you surely mean "there could be" or "I think there should be", right?  "There must be" seems to carry the strength of an inevitable deduction, which doesn't make sense to me.  (A lot of things are different between a ball and a punctured ball that mean it won't surprise me if a theorem "abundantly true" for one is false for the other!)